# using gcc -m32 flag cannot find -lgcc and -lgcc_s

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, 32bit-64bit, nasm

I'm trying to compile a 32 bit assembly code(NASM) on my 64 bit Linux, but I can't, I have tried others tutorials about it and I installed ia32-libs...

When I try run it as:

```
gcc asm1.o -o asm1
```

i386 of the file input `asm1.o' is incompatible with the output i386:x86-64

And when I try run it as:

```
gcc -m32 asm1.o -o asm1
```

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: connot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Thanks for helps.

OBS: Sorry for my english, I'm not from US.

Comment: Did you try installing the development package for it?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have installed: build-essential, libc6-dev-i386, libc6-dev and ia32-libs. I'm using Linux Mint 16 x64.

Comment: @dxhj You may also need to install `gcc-multilib`.

Comment: @dxhj Please convert what you have learned to an answer and accept it, that may also be very helpful to others.

Comment: I'll do it. @leeduhem

Comment: N.B. English is not from the US either

Comment: But the standard english is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to install **gcc-multilib**.

Comment: At least recently and on Debian, it should be enough to install the necessary libs only (instead of the whole bunch of multi-architectural packages that `gcc-multilib` contains. So something like `lib32gcc-8-dev` (on current Debian Buster) is enough (it picks up additional subpackages) to get basic programs to work with `-m32`.