# Cannot find -lgcc when building 32bit program with -m32 on an 64bit machine ( gcc, docker )

Tags: linux, docker, gcc, x86

I would like to build a simple hello world C program for linux in 32 bit. I tried to do it with docker ( because the OS on my machine is not Linux )

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM gcc:4.9
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libc6-dbg libc6-dbg:i386 gcc-multilib libc-dev:i386 gcc-4.9-base:i386
```

I build it like this:

```
docker build -t my-gcc .
```

Then I try to use it like this:

```
docker run --rm -v ${pwd}:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp my-gcc gcc -m32 -o hello hello.c
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.4/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What do I wrong? How is it possible to fix it?
I've found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294004/using-gcc-m32-flag-cannot-find-lgcc-and-lgcc-s), but they suggest `gcc-multilib`, which I already installed.

---

The host machine is Windows 10 x64, with WSL2. But as far as I know, this should not matter. I would like to build x86 32bit linux binaries with gcc.

Comment: Unknown OS, version https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68429527/edit Please edit the question. ..... How about installing gcc-??-plugin-dev-i686-linux-gnu, which also installs as dependency `gcc-??-i686-linux-gnu` providing `/usr/lib/gcc-cross/i686-linux-gnu/??/libcc1.so`

Comment: @KnudLarsen I edited the question. What to substitute ??? for?

Comment: Just a hint. I guess you want like 32bit libgcc_s.so and a 32bit linker. New example https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=libgcc_s.so → →  libgcc-8-dev-i386-cross → `libgcc1-i386-cross` → → `/usr/i686-linux-gnu/lib/libgcc_s.so.1` ........... My ?? are  for gcc version. 10 was replaced with ?? . there are packages 6, 7, 8, 10.

Comment: "Multi-lib" is nice for running 32bit apps. .... Building 32bit apps the easy way : Install a 32bit OS https://www.debian.org/distrib/ → 32-bit PC netinst iso →   https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/i386/iso-cd/debian-10.10.0-i386-netinst.iso ...... ( Or 32bit Ubuntu docker image ).

Comment: Yes, WSL2 (unlike WSL1) can run a Linux kernel with CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION, making it possible to install gcc-multilib packages to get 32-bit libc and libgcc.

Comment: `sudo apt install gcc-4.9-multilib`?

Answer (score 6):

The following Dockerfile fixes the issue:

```
FROM gcc:4.9

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \
        libc6-dev-i386 \
        gcc-multilib \
 && apt-get clean all

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/gcc-4.9", "-m32"]
```

Test:

```
$ docker run --rm -v .:/usr/local/src/:rw my-gcc /usr/local/src/hello.c -o /usr/local/src/hello
$ file hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=32f247e8f3406cde7902af8baf469907b42ed969, not stripped
```

The docker image provides two gcc compilers:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=bash my-gcc
root@efe1bcf6c715:/# which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
root@efe1bcf6c715:/# which gcc-4.9
/usr/bin/gcc-4.9
```

If the `gcc` compiler is used we get several linker errors:

```
$ podman run --rm -v .:/usr/local/src/:rw --entrypoint="gcc" my-gcc:latest -m32 /usr/local/src/hello.c -o /usr/local/src/hello 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.4/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Forcing the `gcc-4.9` one, fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got 32bit compilation to work with gcc 10 (on debian) using this dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \
         build-essential \
         gcc-multilib \
         g++-multilib \
         autoconf \
         automake \
         libtool
```

I also needed various autotools as you can see.

If you need to use configure to setup a tool (cpputest in my case) in 32bit mode then you can use args like this:

```
RUN ./configure \
      CFLAGS=-m32 \
      CXXFLAGS=-m32 \
      LDFLAGS=-m32 \
      --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu \
      --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu
```

And then when you compile inside the container as in your question, with gcc and the correct -m32 flag, it all works nicely without errors:

```
gcc -m32 -O2 main.c -o main.o
```

Comment: You forgot to enable optimization.  Use at least `-O2`, preferably `-O2 -flto` or even `-O3 -flto -march=native` to make a binary that doesn't waste tons of CPU time.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I am using a version of gcc without flto so it wasn't on my radar but yes optimisation should be there for the non debug builds.